# Flask server running on Windows VM displays a black screen when launched remotely through SSH

Tags: flask, ssh, openssh, screen-capture

I have an Ubuntu machine with a Windows virtual machine (VM) running on it. The Windows VM contains a repository that includes a Flask server, launched using a batch file. When manually executed within the VM (either by double-clicking the batch file or running it through the command prompt), the Flask server opens in a CMD window.

The Flask server has an API endpoint called "capture_screen" that returns an image of the Windows screen. For example, accessing the URL "192.168.122.126:8000/capture_screen" displays an image capturing the current contents of the Windows screen.

Here's the implementation of the `get_screenshot` function within the Flask server:

```py
@app.route('/capture_screen')
def get_screenshot():
    SCREENSHOT_PATH.mkdir(exist_ok=True)
    screen_size = get_screen_size()
    sct = mss()
    sct_img = sct.grab({'top': 0, 'left': 0, 'width': screen_size[0], 'height': screen_size[1]})
    filename = str(uuid.uuid4()) + ".png"
    image = cv2.cvtColor(np.array(sct_img), cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
    image[:, :, [0, 2]] = image[:, :, [2, 0]]
    cv2.imwrite(f"{SCREENSHOT_PATH}\\" + filename, image)
    return send_file(f"{SCREENSHOT_PATH}\\" + filename, mimetype='image/gif')
```

The issue arises when executing the batch file that starts the Flask server through an SSH request from the Ubuntu machine to the Windows VM. Although indications suggest that the Flask server starts correctly (responses received for various server requests), the captured images using this script result in a black screen.

The problem seems to occur during the `sct.grab` function, indicating that a black image is saved on the VM and transferred to the Ubuntu machine. Consequently, the issue is not related to file transfer via the server but rather the actual image capture process. It appears that the Flask server runs in a headless environment, detached from the Windows VM's graphical user interface (GUI), and can only interact with the VM's components (e.g., reading files, saving data).

Additionally, here's the `start_flask_server` function used to open the Flask server via SSH from the Ubuntu machine:

```py
def start_flask_server(vm_ip: str, user_name: str, user_password: str):
    def send_start_command_to_vm():
        command = f"sshpass -p {user_password} ssh {user_name}@{vm_ip} " \
                  f"{Utils.get_config(RUN_FLASK_SERVER_BAT_PATH_ON_VM)}"
        result = Utils.run_command_and_return(command)
        logger.info(result.stdout)
    Thread(target=send_start_command_to_vm).start()
```

I would appreciate any insights or suggestions on resolving this issue and capturing the Windows screen correctly through the Flask server.